# All files I write to iCloud are listable but still Not Found

Tags: file, swiftui, icloud

The following code writes files and lists them and checks for if they exist or not. By fact that they can be listed means the directory knows about them, but file manager reports they do not exist.

I have found this behavior in many apps and don't understand how the directory can see a file but not allow me to open it.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var fileNames: [String] = []
    let filemanager = FileManager.default
    var containerUrl: URL?
    {
        let f = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?
            .appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        return f
    }
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading)
        {
            Button("List Files")
            {
                if let documentDirectory = containerUrl
                {
                    fileNames = getFiles(documentDirectory: documentDirectory)
                }
            }
            .onAppear()
            {
                if let documentDirectory = containerUrl
                {
                    fileNames = getFiles(documentDirectory: documentDirectory)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.blue).foregroundColor(Color.white).cornerRadius(5)
            ForEach(fileNames, id:\.self)
            {
                file in
                Text(file)
            }
            
            Button("Write")
            {
                var containerUrl: URL?
                    {
                        return filemanager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
                    }
                //print(containerUrl?.absoluteString)
                    // check for container existence
                    if let url = containerUrl
                    {
                        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: nil)
                        {
                                do
                                {
                                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                                }
                        }
                        let docURL = url.appendingPathComponent("Text \(Date())").appendingPathExtension("txt")
                        let string = "Mary had a little lamb"
                        try? string.write(to: docURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                        
                        fileNames = getFiles(documentDirectory: url)
                    } else
                    {
                        print("No such luck")
                    }
            }.background(Color.red).foregroundColor(Color.white).cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
    
    func getFiles(documentDirectory: URL) -> [String]
    {
        var fileNames:[String] = []
        do
        {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
                at: documentDirectory,
                includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
            )
            
            for url in directoryContents
            {
                print(url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent)
                if url.hasDirectoryPath
                {
                    let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
                        at: url,
                        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
                    )
                    for file in files
                    {
                        print("  \(file.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            for url in directoryContents
            {
                let found = (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.absoluteString)) ? ",Found" : ",Not Found"
                print(url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent)
                fileNames.append((url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent) + found)
                try filemanager.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: url)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
        return fileNames
    }
}

extension URL
{
    var typeIdentifier: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier }
    var isMP3: Bool { typeIdentifier == "public.mp3" }
    var localizedName: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName }
    var hasHiddenExtension: Bool {
        get { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.hasHiddenExtensionKey]))?.hasHiddenExtension == true }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.hasHiddenExtension = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that iCloud files will have a .icloud extension appended to the end of the url until they have been downloaded. The show as Not Found because they aren't on your local device until they are downloaded using

FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: myDocumentUrl)

The download isn't immediate and once it is on your device, it will no longer be hidden (url starts with a .) and won't have the .icloud extension.